# Musical Isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I'm studying from Fecko's *Differential Geometry and Lie Groups for Physicists*, and in the part introducing metric tensors, Fecko introduces the musical isomorphisms between the tangent and cotangent space as the following maps for some metric tensor $g$. 
$$\flat{g}:v \mapsto g(v, \cdot)$$
and similarly,
$$\sharp{g}:\alpha \mapsto g^{-1}(\alpha, \cdot)$$
Fecko then gives an exercise to show these equal, in component form, the following:
$$g_{ab}v^b$$ and $$g^{ab}\alpha_b$$ respectively. How do I calculate $g(v, \cdot)$ or $g^{-1}(\alpha, \cdot)$ ? I'm not sure where to begin... I'm new to tensors and get lost easily with the notation.

Answer (score 0):

If the components of the metric tensor $g$ are $g_{ab} = g(e_a,e_b)$ and $v= \sum v^a e_a$  then $g(v, \cdot)$ is a 1-form, which in the dual basis $\{f_k\}$ its $c$-component is $g(v^a e_a, e_c)= v^a g_{ac}$.

Considering the inverse metric, whose components are $g^{m n}$ in the above dual basis, you can obtain in a similar way the second expression.